# Infer generic from properties

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Let's have an interface that describes a rating form with example results to preview how it will look after all participants have submitted the form:

```
interface Rating {
  maxRating: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;
  exampleResults: number[]; // E.g. [0, 0, 0, 2, 5] = 2 votes for 4*, 5 votes for 5*.
}
```

This naive implementation doesn't check whether `exampleResults`'s length is the same as the value of `maxRating`. So instead I tried:

```
interface Rating<T extends 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10> {
  maxRating: T;
  exampleResults: Tuple<number, T>; // Touple definition is omitted for simplification
}
```

but when I try to use it:

```
const rating: Rating = {
  maxRating: 5,
  exampleResults: [0, 0, 0, 1, 4],
}
```

I get this error:

> Generic type 'Rating' requires 1 type argument(s).

But obviously TypeScript *can* infer type by reading the value of `maxRating`.

Now I get it if TypeScript doesn't support such inference today, but is there another way I can use to restrict type of one property based on value of another?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to infer/to know `maxRating` upfront. Consider this example:

```js
type Max = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;

type Tuple<Length extends Max, Result extends number[] = []> =
  Result['length'] extends Length
  ? Result
  : Tuple<Length, [...Result, number]>

interface Rating<M extends Max> {
  maxRating: M
  exampleResults: Tuple<M>
}

const rating: Rating<5> = {
  maxRating: 5,
  exampleResults: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // ok
}

const rating2: Rating<5> = {
  maxRating: 5,
  exampleResults: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // expected error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgDygXigRigHygJi1AZnwBZ8BWfANnwHZ8AOfATnzQAYBuAKC9EigAqAVzAAbCAB4AMhAB2Ac2AALKBATA5AEwDOsRABooAJQjaho4KvVbdsoQFsARhABOAbQC6KKJ4B8KLihjU3NgNwBycQVlcK81DVkdKBlopUCoAH5gswt0gC5BEXFpOUUlQzcAOmqTHOBDOydXD18eAEtZDRcAMzgAY2gjOGAO%20QkYKwSk%20AR-AG90%200QhkYUCmHS1OHsxCFrQ7QLhXfHWgF8ePoB7WW1LF2HRgpXRiTJ-VAWgpYQXtagyPpNghtrt9hZDj40IYcIYCIZiIYyF4APQoqBXADWXAuXGut3ujwUOGeRLG728XygPz%208gKgOBoPE4OAkLc0NwcIRSMMlFR6LUkD6Gk0qhcLiuLhxQA)

TypeScript is unable to infer `maxRating` from the object, like you did.

There is another way to infer `maxRating`. You can use a function:

```js
const handler = <N extends Max>(r: Rating<N>) => r

handler({ maxRating: 10, exampleResults: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }) // ok
```